# Intersection of kernel and a basis for the image of a skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $W$ be a skew-symmetric matrix of dimension $n$ with $\det(W)=0$. If $1\leq \text{Null}(W)<n$, it's clear that the image has dimension greater that 1. My question is if $\beta$ is a basis of image of $W$, could it happen that $\beta\cap \ker(W)\ne \emptyset$ or $\beta\cap \ker(W)\ne \left\{0\right\}$?

In fact, I only need to know if $Wv\ne 0$ for all elements in $\beta$.

I really need help with this problem.

Comment: "Symmetric Matrix". Simmering matrix is something else. Why do you conclude that $1\le Null(W)<n$? Take $W=0$. Then $Wv=0$ for all $v$.

Comment: Isn't a conclusion is an hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming real matrices, you have the general equality
$$
\ker W = (\text{ran}\,W^T)^\perp.
$$
Since $W^T=-W$ and $\text{ran}\,(-W)=\text{ran}\,W$, you get 
$$
\ker W = (\text{ran}\,W)^\perp.
$$
So $$\ker W\,\cap\,\text{ran}\,W=\{0\}.$$

Comment: What's the meaning of $\perp$ in the matrix, sorry but I don't remember that

Comment: It's for subspaces, and it's "orthogonal".

Comment: Thank's, another question do you know some book where I can find the general result?